# How to do the loop along a 3D vector with a known length by python

Tags: python

I have done a point filter programme in a 3D plane, but I need to do a loop along a known 3D normal vector with a known length. Many thanks for the help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

point  = sta[10]    #starting points
normal = axe[10]    #normal vector

d = -point.dot(normal)

# create x,y
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3.,-2.,101), np.linspace(-11.,-10.,101))



# calculate corresponding z
z = (-normal[0] * xx - normal[1] * yy - d) * 1. /normal[2]
f=[]
for i in xrange(len(xx)-1):
    for j in xrange(len(xx)-1):
        if (xx[i][j]-sta[10][0])**2 + (yy[i][j]-sta[10][1])**2 + (z[i][j]-sta[10][2])**2 > float(rad[0])**2:
            xx[i][j]=NaN
            yy[i][j]=NaN
            z[i][j]=NaN
```

Comment: What is 'sta' and 'axe'? You have defined numpy as np in the start then used 'numpy' in the code.

Comment: As I said, the sta is a array including starting 3D points, is a centre of circle. Axe is a array including normal vector.

Comment: Did you use len(xx) by purpose two times ? Intuitively I would suggest using len(yy) and len(xx)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using meshgrid and `xx`, `yy` and `z` have the same shape, numpy's broadcasting policy will automatically do what you need. Try this:

```
invalid = (xx-sta[10,0])**2 + (yy-sta[10,1])**2 + (z-sta[10,2])**2 > float(rad[0])**2
xx[invalid]=np.NaN
yy[invalid]=np.NaN
z[invalid]=np.NaN
```

It creates a boolean mask `invalid` which contains `True` for all entries that satisfy the condition. You can then use this mask to set the corresponding values to `NaN`.
*Note that you can use tuples to index numpy arrays. I.e. `myArray[a][b]` is equivalent to `myArray[a, b]`.*

Also note that I assumed you excluded the last entries by accident. If it was on purpose that you used `xrange(len(xx)-1)` rather than `xrange(len(xx))`, it is getting a bit uglier and you have to do it like this:

```
invalid = (xx[:-1,:-1]-sta[10,0])**2 + (yy[:-1,:-1]-sta[10,1])**2 + (z[:-1,:-1]-sta[10,2])**2 > float(rad[0])**2
xx[:-1,:-1][invalid]=np.NaN
yy[:-1,:-1][invalid]=np.NaN
z[:-1,:-1][invalid]=np.NaN
```

Comment: Yes, but my question is how to do this as a loop along a 3d vector. I am so struggling with this.

Comment: @linneo I'm sorry but repeating what you already stated twice in the question's title and your actual "question" doesn't help me helping you... I've shown you the "right" way to do what you did in your loop construct. If that isn't what you need, please provide more information on your problem. For example: Which vector is it you want to loop along? Where is the length you're talking about? What do you want to produce during the loop? What do you want to achieve at all? A working code example with desired output would also be neat...